# bucle inentendible en js con dom

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

me está pasando una cosa y no entiendo el, ¿por qué?...
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio manejando el dom en el que asigno eventos a diferentes botones. Pues dentro del evento cuando pulso un boton me hace un bucle y comprueba tantas veces el botón como cuadrados añadidos  tenga. No  se si me he explicado bien. Os pongo el codigo para que veáis que puedo mejorar.

Las funciones que salen dentro las tengo por si creeis que sea un fallo de alguna funcion, aunque no creo.

```
var arrayInvitados=[];
const formulario = document.getElementById("registrar");
var elementos=document.querySelector('#invitedList');
 //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {

        formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
            e.preventDefault();
            addInvitadosHtml();

        elementos.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            var botonOrdenar = document.getElementById("filtrar").checked;

            var tipoBoton = e.target.tagName;
            var tipoClass = e.target.className;
            if(tipoClass==="edit"){
                var padre = event.target.parentNode;
                var primerH = padre.firstChild.textContent;
                var newName = prompt("Introduce el nuevo nombre");
                var nuevospan = document.createElement("span");
                nuevospan.textContent=newName;
                var nodoviejo = padre.firstChild
                padre.replaceChild(nuevospan, nodoviejo);
                changeName(primerH,newName);

            }else if(tipoClass==="remove"){
                var padreR = event.target.parentNode;
                var padrePad = padreR.parentNode;
                var nombreSpan = padreR.firstChild.textContent;
                var confirmar=confirm("¿estás seguro?");
                if(confirmar){padrePad.removeChild(padreR);removeInvited(nombreSpan);}


            }else if(tipoClass==="check"){
                var padre = event.target.parentNode;
                var nombre=  padre.previousSibling.textContent;
                if(controlCheck(nombre)){
                    var padrePadre = padre.parentNode;
                    padrePadre.setAttribute("class","responded");
                }else{
                    var padre = event.target.parentNode;
                    var padrePadre = padre.parentNode;
                    padrePadre.removeAttribute("class","responded");
                }
                //var controlCasilla = document.getElementsByClassName("check")[0].checked;
            }
            /*if(botonOrdenar){
                    confirmados();
                }*/

        });


        });
```

Comment: El evento que me comprueba es el de elementos.addeventListener... si pulso una vez y tengo agregados dos **<li>** en mi html, comprueba el primer boton que sea hijo de **<li>** realiza lo que tenga que hacer, pero no acaba ahi sino que va a comprobar el siguiente boton, y detecta que tambien está tocado y vuelve a realizar la accion en este caso la deshace, y si hubiese una tercera etiqueta entraría otra vez...

Comment: Vale lo conseguí, lo unico que tenía que hacer es que el primer evento abre y cierra despues de las primeras funciones y yo lo tenia englobando a todo por eso comprobaba todas las etiquetas. Un saludo.